# How Do I Add an Error Message for Certain Integers?

Tags: java, android

I am very new to programming and I have made a very simple guessing game app in android studio but I wondered how I can add in an error message if a user types in an integer below 1 and above 100? This is my code currently:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText txtGuess;
    private Button btnGuess;
    private TextView lblOutput;
    private int theNumber;
    private int numberOfTries;
    public void checkGuess() {
        String guessText = txtGuess.getText().toString();
        String message = "";
        try {
            lblOutput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;
            int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessText);
            if (guess < theNumber)
                message = guess + " is too low. Try again.";
            else if (guess > theNumber)
                message = guess + " is too high. Try again.";
            else {
                message = guess +
                        " is correct! This took you " + numberOfTries + " tries! Let's play again.";
                lblOutput.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                newGame();
                numberOfTries = 0;

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Enter a whole number between 1 and 100.";
        }
        finally {
            lblOutput.setText(message);
            txtGuess.requestFocus();
            txtGuess.selectAll();
        }


    }

    public void newGame() {
        theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtGuess);
        btnGuess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);
        lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
        newGame();
        btnGuess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkGuess();

            }
        });
        txtGuess.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                checkGuess();
                return true;
```

It currently just tells the user that the number is too high. Help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you want to throw a Java `Exception` or do you want an "error message" widget on your page somewhere?

Comment: You need to describe in more details what you are trying to achieve and what problem you are facing. From what is written it is hard to tell what's wrong with your code.

Comment: When the user enters a number, for example, 589, I want `lblOutput` to read "Enter a whole number between 1 and 100" as in the case of my `catch (Exception e)` which shows the error if a user tries to input anything but an integer. Currently it just tells the user that their guess is too high because of the `if (guess > theNumber)`

Comment: `finally` should only be used to clean up resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw a custom Exception if a certain condition is fullfilled:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html

like:

```
if( number > 100 && number < 1){
    throw new CustomException("Number not in defined range");
}


public class CustomExceptionextends Exception {

    public CustomException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can create a method validate:

public boolean validate (int number) {
}

that will return true if given number is valid or false if it's out of range or wrong format etc.

Then in your checkGuess method call validate() on user's input and if the returned value is equal to false display Toast.

custom Exception is a way to go as well.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder why you want to use exceptions here. you can just check user inputs in a true while and if input is valid you can break the loop.

```
while(true){ //check input is valid
  if(inputNumber < 1 || inputNumber > 100){
  sout("plz enter number between 1 to 100");
  }
  else{
  break();
  }
}
//now that you are sure input is valid go on.
```

the point in here is user wont get exception each time he enters a invalid number & he can try to enter numbers repeatedly without being interrupted by apps exception and when he enters a valid one he can go on.